# using CreateFile on c# returns isInvalid = true

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, io, pinvoke

I'm using CreateFile as shown below, and keep getting isInvalid = true, no meter what I do, however, the error code returning from "Marshal.GetLastWin32Error" is changing according to the path I’m trying to access.

Here are the paths and their corresponding error codes:

1. @lpFileName = "c:\” -> 3
2. @lpFileName = "\\127.0.0.1\share\" ->
   123
3. @lpFileName = "c:\share\" -> 5

Obviously "c:\" does exists, and as far as I know "\\127.0.0.1\share\" is a valid UNC
and I gave every possible right to everyone on the target computer, both NTFS and share.
None of those make sense.

My system is Server 2008R2
Help please.

CreateFile:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        LPCTSTR lpFileName,
        DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
        DWORD dwShareMode,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
        DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
        DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        HANDLE hTemplateFile
        );
```

With the flags below:

```
DWORD dwIoControlCode,
        LPCTSTR lpFileName,
        DWORD dwDesiredAccess = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        DWORD dwShareMode = FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_READ,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes = default(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES),
        DWORD dwCreationDisposition = OPEN_EXISTING,
        DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes = 0,
        HANDLE hTemplateFile = default(IntPtr)
        )
```

and flag values:

```
 public const DWORD
        GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000,
        GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x2,
        FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x1,
        OPEN_EXISTING = 0x3;
```

Comment: why go unmamaged, when you can do the same with managed code?

Comment: I need to get UNC's drive info I only use CreateFile to get the handle back

Comment: what kind of Info do you need?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Read Directories section in this article.

Comment: For this meter I need the disk size but I will also need the amount of free space. For that task I'm using GetDiskFreeSpaceEx, which also, not working

Comment: Do they allow "DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes = 0" ?

Comment: @Alex Farber Thanks man!!!  That was it, I had to change dwFlagsAndAttributes to FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS =
0x02000000
Write this as answer and I will choose it as best answer

Comment: This question is odd. What is `isInvalid`? And where is the code that makes the calls. That's where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

CreateFile function (Windows)

Directories

To open a directory using CreateFile, specify the FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS flag as part of dwFlagsAndAttributes.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using unmanaged code here? Try the standard managed options:

```
using(var fs = new FileStream(...)){

}
```

Comment: I need to get UNC's drive info I only use CreateFile to get the handle back

Comment: @choppy - use fs.Handle once it's opened. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.handle(v=vs.90).aspx